# NSAutoreleasepool: Memory Management problem in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, memory-management, ios4, memory-leaks, nsautoreleasepool

```
__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x4c70ec0 of class UISegmentedControl autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x4c70ec0 of class UISegmentedControl autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x4c70ec0 of class UISegmentedControl autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x4c70ec0 of class UISegmentedControl autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x4c70ec0 of class UISegmentedControl autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

This is what I get as warning in console. Though it doesnt create a crash but seems to be some memory management issue.

What could be wrong?

I have not autoreleased my segemented control.

Comment: are you creating the control in main.m, or in a parallel process?

Comment: you're going to need to post some code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem commonly arise when you are using multi-threading. 
If you using threading, should create autorelease pool for that thread

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

//Code....

[pool release];
```

Comment: Which code should be written between `NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];` and `[pool release]`??

Comment: The function or any code which you run in thread (if its not in main thread, main thread has default autorelease pool, if you open main.m in your project, you ca see this.) should have autorelease pool.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UISegmentedControl in a thread that is not main thread as @Martin said, it is not safe.

[UIKit Framework Reference - Introduction](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/Introduction/Introduction.html)

> Note: For the most part, UIKit classes
>   should be used only from an
>   application’s main thread. This is
>   particularly true for classes derived
>   from UIResponder or that involve
>   manipulating your application’s user
>   interface in any way.

Comment: I am using a activity indicator and UILabel inside my thread. Can that be a reason? If yes, what is a way to get around this problem?

Comment: Use NSObject -performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone or Grand Central Dispatch Main Queue for a activity indicator and UILabel manipulation.